# Replace string with variable for golang proxy

Tags: go

I'm trying to use the http proxy code here

```
proxyUrl := url.Parse(strings.Replace("%v", RandomProxyAddress()))
http.DefaultTransport = &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)}
```

Tells me there are too many arguments  in the url.Parse

But when I try

```
proxyUrl := url.Parse(RandomProxyAddress())
http.DefaultTransport = &http.Transport{Proxy: http.ProxyURL(proxyUrl)}
```

I get `./main.go:138: multiple-value url.Parse() in single-value context`

When I tried a string replace it also tells me too many varibles.  Not sure how to get my proxy to work with the url.Parse

Comment: [`strings.Replace`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace) takes 4 arguments. Are you looking for [`fmt.Sprintf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf)?

Comment: yes that was the issue thank you @JimB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, url.Parse returns two variables, a URL and an error, as per the [docs here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#Parse).

Secondly, instead of `strings.Replace` you probably meant to use `fmt.Sprintf("%v", RandomProxyAddress())`, assuming `RandomProxyAddress()` returns a string, or something that formats into the string you want. So all in all, you should have:

```
addr := fmt.Sprintf("%v", RandomProxyAddress())
proxyURL, err := url.Parse(addr)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

That said, the `fmt.Sprintf` would be unnecessary if `RandomProxyAddress()` already returns a string. [Check the docs for `fmt` and `fmt.Sprintf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/). And if you really did mean to use `strings.Replace`, notice that it [requires four arguments](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace), not two.

Comment: Not quite sure what the downvote was for.